# ¿Hay alguna manera de introducir código JavaScript en WordPress desde un archivo externo?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, script, innerhtml

He probado a meterlo desde el archivo functions.php de la carpeta del tema pero no funciona el innerHTML, he probado otro tipo de soluciones que tampoco han resultado efectivas.

Esto es lo que me sale en editar, osea el functions.php : function load_js_assets() { if( is_page( 380573 ) ) { wp_enqueue_script('data', 'rig-mining.cz/data.js', array('jquery'), '', false); } if( is_page( 380573 ) ) { wp_enqueue_script('tarjetas', 'rig-mining.cz/tarjeta.js', array('jquery'), '', false); } } add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');

Comment: Hay una opción... buscar en google. Por ejemplo, https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368

Comment: En Wordpress tienes que hacerlo por medio de [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), asegurándote de poner la ruta correcta del archivo `.js` que quieres incluir. [Está todo explicado aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). Si no te funciona, pulsa en [edit] y muéstranos lo que tienes en `functions.php`, y dinos la ruta exacta de tu archivo `.js`. Si ves algún error, escribe en la pregunta el mensaje completo de error.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Esto es lo que me sale en editar, osea el functions.php :                                 function load_js_assets() {
 if( is_page( 380573 ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script('data', 'https://rig-mining.cz/data.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
 } 
    if( is_page( 380573 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('tarjetas', 'https://rig-mining.cz/tarjeta.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega esa información relevante en la pregunta, no en comentarios. Observa que en tu función sólo estarías incluyendo los scripts en determinadas páginas, las que no tengan esos IDs no cargarán los scripts. ¿Eres consciente de eso? ¿Si abres una de esas páginas los scripts no se cargan? ¿Qué errores muestra la consola?

Comment: Solo quiero que afecte a una página, el error que sale en la consola de comandos es este: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
    at tarjeta.js?ver=5.9.3:68:7
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at tablePrint (tarjeta.js?ver=5.9.3:52:15)
    at tarjeta.js?ver=5.9.3:44:7

Answer (score 1):

La manera correcta es haciendo uso de la funcion [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) que es la que usas en tu código dentro del archivo functions.php del theme. Lo que te esta ocurriendo no tiene que ver con insertar el script, ya que lo estas haciendo, el error que obtienes en consola proviene del Javascript que esta en "tarjetas.js", el error te indica que no puede obtener las propiedades de algo que no existe, probablemente alguna variable que estés usando en dicho código no está definida.

Ejemplo de uso sería:

> ```
> function load_js_assets() { 
>     if( is_page( 380573 ) ) {
>         wp_enqueue_script('data', plugins_url( 'rig-mining.cz/data.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', false);
>     }
>     
>     if( is_page( 380573 ) ) {
>         wp_enqueue_script('tarjetas', plugins_url( 'rig-mining.cz/tarjeta.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', false);
>     }
> }
>
> add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
> ```